# "not a multipath request" error when uploading local file to server

Tags: java, vbscript

```vb
OPTION EXPLICIT

DIM myFile, myDate, myName, xml

myName = "shipment"
myDate = "20150708"

'The file we are uploading

myFile = "C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\myFile.txt"

Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
xml.Open "POST", "http://localhost:8080//myProject/myClass/myMethod", myName, myDate, myFile, False
xml.Send
Set xml = Nothing
```

For the above VBScript I am getting the error

> Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

I fixed the above error by changing the above code to below code

```vb
...
...
Set xml = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")

xml.Open "POST", "http://localhost:8080//myProject/myClass/myMethod" , False  
xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
xml.Send "sName=shipment&sDate=20150708&sFile=C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\myFile.txt"

Set xml = Nothing
```

Now I am getting the below error at server side:

> Error: The current request is not a multipart request

`FileUpload.java` (server-side code in Java):

```java
...
...
@RequestMapping(value = "/myMethod", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody String processData(
        @RequestParam("myName") String fileName,
        @RequestParam("myDate") String fileDate,
        @RequestParam("myFile") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
 ...
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not actually sending a file. You're just sending the *filename* as a string. You can't just assign a filename to a form/post variable and expect VBScript to upload it. You'll need to open the file and stream the bytes as part of your HTTP request. For example:

```vb
Const adTypeBinary = 1
Const adModeReadWrite = 3

' Load the file into an ADO Stream object... '
Dim objStream
Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Mode = adModeReadWrite
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.Open
objStream.LoadFromFile "C:\Users\TestUser\Desktop\myFile.txt"

' Create an XML/HTTP request... '
Dim objHttp
Set objHttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
objHttp.Open "POST", "http://localhost:8080//myProject/myClass/myMethod", False
objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Length", xmlStream.Size
objHttp.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "multipart/form-data"

' Now read the entire stream and send it in the request body... '
objHttp.Send objStream.Read(objStream.Size)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to send extra parameters like filename and filedate along with actual file. could you please let me know how can i post the data to server.